# How to get Maliit Keyboard working on linux? (Mint)

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am trying to get maliit virtual keyboard working on linux.

I have built and installed [maliit-framework](https://github.com/maliit/framework) and [maliit-plugins](https://github.com/maliit/plugins) on a Mint Cinnamon 64 bit installed on a virtual machine. The example app "plainqt" runs, it starts the maliit server process when I press the start button. But nothing happens when I select an input field, no keyboard, no error message. It does give a warning `virtual void MaliitKeyboard::Logic::WordEngine::setEnabled(bool) No backend available, cannot enable word engine!`. Is a word engine strictly necessary for the keyboard to just simply show?

There doesn't seem to be much documentation. There was a wiki once, at least parts of it can be found on [waybackmachine](http://web.archive.org/web/20130606035734/https://wiki.maliit.org/Documentation/Installing). It seems outdated though. The github repository has been updated several times since the wiki went down, and fx maliit-keyboard-viewer.exe seems to have been removed.

Has anyone compiled and installed a recent version of maliit framework and plugins? What is the minimum setup required?

**Current setup details**

I am running it through Qt Creator with gcc compiler

I have added these additional arguments for qmake: `CONFIG+=nodoc CONFIG+=nohwkeyboard CONFIG+=noxcb`

I have added make install step under build steps; command: `ssh-askpass` , arguments: `Sudo Password | sudo -S make install`

I have set the `QT_IM_MODULE` environment variable on the system: `export QT_IM_MODULE=Maliit`

I have also set the `QT_IM_MODULE` environment variable to Maliit in project settings in Qt Creator under build environment

I have run `gconftool-2 -s --type list --list-type string /maliit/onscreen/enabled "[libmaliit-keyboard-plugin.so,en_gb]"` and `gconftool-2 -s --type list --list-type string /maliit/onscreen/active "[libmaliit-keyboard-plugin.so,en_gb]"` as per the readme of maliit-plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just managed to run the `maliit-server` and keyboard.

You might be missing the step (this is what I missed as well), which is to compile and install `input-context` which is somehow is not installed by default (in my case anyway).

Stop / kill all the `maliit-server` instances and close the app.

```
export QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS=/path/to/your/qt/plaugins
cd framework-master/input-content
qmake
make
make install // sudo if your plugin directory needs root permission
```

start the server

```
maliit-server &
maliit-exampleapp-plainqt
```

clicking on the input field should bring up the keyboard. Word engine isn't necessary (I don't have one and get the same warnings!)

I'm now facing another issue which I asked here: [maliit keyboard - black box on letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283961/maliit-keyboard-black-box-on-letters)

Comment: doh, it's even an option in the maliit-framework.pro `qt5-inputcontext : Compile with Qt5 input context, replaces the one currently provided by Qt ` I passed `CONFIG+=qt5-inputcontext` to qmake and I now get a keyboard. Thank you

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Are you getting the same black box as well? Thanks

Comment: No black box for me. However when I hover the mouse above a key, a box with the character pops up above the key, which is fine, but sometimes it appears top left corner of the keyboard instead :s